# What is the point using Redux (with ReactJS)?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I understand Redux adds global states to plain ReactJS, but you can do the same with React ContextAPI. So why use Redux (instead of the ContextApi)?

Comment: Context is not suited for real global state, but more of a dependency injection mechanism - it doesn't offer a way to granularly subscribe. https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2021/01/context-redux-differences/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are the same ... But Redux was exists first.

Context API was introduce as a solution to React prop drilling in React version 16.3.

That's it